# Ubuntu Studio: No sound in audio production programs

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I just installed Ubuntu Studio and when trying to use the audio production programs, I cannot hear any sound out of my speakers. When I open Mozilla however and play a Youtube video, I can hear sound.

How do I configure the audio production programs to output through my computer speakers?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, go through [this introduction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ProAudioIntro). It might solve your issues.